# REST API - MoveToUsingPath

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to move file on SharePoint from one site collection to another using Power Automate, but they can have special characters in their name or path.

I wanted to use GetFileByServerRelativePath and MoveToUsingPath, that manage # and %.

The first part GetFileByServerRelativePath  is working well, I can find the document, but when I add MoveToUsingPath I get an error : **"An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected"**

Here is the request (I removed Power Automate parameters for URLs, I use *encodeUriComponent* function):

```
_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedURL=SourceURL)/MoveToUsingPath(newpath=EncodedDestinationURL,moveOperations=1)
```

For now I'm trying on the same site collection, when it's working on the same site, I'll try on 2 sites.
Source = /sites/ArchiveSandBox/Source Library/test #1/Book%2.xlsx
Destination = /sites/ArchiveSandBox/Destination/test #1/Book%2.xlsx

Can you help me with this?

Thanks

Note: I tried MoveTo, CopyTo, and I have the error : **"Folder "test #1" does not exist."**